# What is the most widely spoken L2 (second language) in the EU28, besides English?

Tags: motivation

Many people are influenced/motivated to learn certain languages by how [widely spoken](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/what-are-the-most-widespread-languages-besides-english-spanish-and-french) they are. To that end, *besides English*, what is the most widely spoken language in the [EU28](http://publications.europa.eu/code/pdf/370000en.htm)? Bonus points for listing the top 5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about trivia and it has nothing to do about the process of language acquisition.

Comment: @bytebuster It has to do with motivation to learn a language.

Comment: I fail to see how the top 5 most spoken L2 languages deals with anything related motivation to learn

Comment: @AnthonyPham Similar idea behind this question: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/what-are-the-most-widespread-languages-besides-english-spanish-and-french. A highly spoken or widely spoken language is a strong motivation for many language learners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the [European Commission's Eurobarometer data (page 22)](http://ec.europa.eu/commfrontoffice/publicopinion/archives/ebs/ebs_386_en.pdf) the top 3 list of most widespread second languages:

1. German - 5%
2. French - 5%
3. Spanish - 3%

The top 5 list of most widespread foreign languages in early 2012 (without English what is spoken by the 20.09% of the EU's population as a foreign language):

2. French - 7.62%
3. German - 6.69%
4. Spanish - 4.6%
5. Russian - 2.71%
6. Italian - 1.79%

You can check the full list: [here](http://languageknowledge.eu/).

Comment: Please edit your answer to answer what I asked, which was as a second language only and *not including English*.

Comment: Sorry about that. I found data about the top 3 L2 languages so I edited my answer.

Comment: Your previous answer was good, just take out English and add in the 5th language. Please add it back, in addition to this information (along with the relevant page number in the big PDF).

Comment: It's interesting that Spanish is FAR more popular in the US than it is in Europe. It makes sense, but the disparity is huge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_commonly_learned_foreign_languages_in_the_United_States#K-12